# Why doesn't this check constraint work?3

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table question(`id_q`, `question`,`picture`, `answer`) and I need to make a constraint that doesn't allow me to insert a new question in the table if the question contains in it's text 'indicator semnification' and the picture is null.

I tried this way:

```
ALTER TABLE question ADD
CONSTRAINT CK_question check (((question like '%indicator semnification%') and 
                               (picture in(null))) or 
                               (question not like '%indicator semnification%'));
```

but it doesn't works.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Most probably you are using MySQL and MySQL doesn't support Check Constraint.

Comment: @OlimpiaMuntea I've fixed it for you, but next time you ask a database question make sure you tag the proper DBMS.

Comment: Is the problem possibly that you have a column name and table name the same? Try making one of them unique.

Comment: I did this and still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE question
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_question check (((question like '%indicator semnification%') and
                                      (picture in(null))) or
                                      (question not like '%indicator semnification%')
                                     )
```

The problem is probably the `picture in (null)`.  This will never return true.  Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE question
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_question check (((question like '%indicator semnification%') and
                                      (picture is null)) or
                                      (question not like '%indicator semnification%')
                                     )
```

Also, if you are using MySQL, you can express constraints, but they are not implemented.

EDIT:

The above fixes the logic in your version.  I think the logic you really want is:

```
ALTER TABLE question
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_question check ((question not like '%indicator semnification%') or 
                                      (picture is not null)
                                     ) ;
```

Or, equivalently (when `question` is not null):

```
ALTER TABLE question
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_question check (not ((question like '%indicator semnification%') and 
                                           (picture is null))
                                     ) ;
```

Comment: Ouhh!! Nice catch +1 but what if OP is using MySQL :) ?

Comment: @Rahul . . . If you want check constraints in MySQL, you need to use triggers.

Comment: I'm using Oracle. The constraint stil doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your constraint definition like below, using `()` your condition set(s)

```
ALTER TABLE question ADD
CONSTRAINT CK_question check (question LIKE '%indicator semnification%'  
                               OR
                               (picture IS NULL  
                                OR  
                               question NOT LIKE '%indicator semnification%'));
```